# How to read Decimal(38,23) column into C# with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, decimal, precision

I have a database column of type `decimal(38, 23)`.

I'm aware that this means it can store decimals that don't fit in a 28-place precision .NET decimal.

However, I also know that all the individual values in the database *do* fit in a .NET decimal. i.e. each individual number has no more than 28 significant figures, and does not exceed 10^(+/-28)

I want to use crude EF

```
SqlQuery<T>("SELECT * FROM myTable)
```

to read the data, but when I do so I get a conversion overflow error (will update with exact Exception message shortly).
I feel like I *ought* to be able to get this working, though. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So what happens when you just use `decimal`?

Comment: D'oh! Didn't notice that I didn't include that :( Will amend

Comment: You can try and make your own EF specific value type and use that throughout your domain or do the necessary conversion to primitive types as you need,